# Pyinstaller error xfd module

Tags: python, cmd, compiler-errors, pip, pyinstaller

I installed Pyinstaller, but when I type `pyinstaller` in CMD as administrator, it will print this:

```
C:\Users\Kuba>pyinstaller
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.2', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "c:\users\kuba\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 564, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "c:\users\kuba\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2608, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "c:\users\kuba\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2268, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "c:\users\kuba\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2274, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "c:\users\kuba\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import PyInstaller.building.build_main
  File "c:\users\kuba\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 32, in <module>
    from ..depend import bindepend
  File "c:\users\kuba\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 38, in <module>
    from ..utils.win32.winmanifest import RT_MANIFEST
  File "c:\users\kuba\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 97, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.utils.win32 import winresource
  File "c:\users\kuba\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 20, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "c:\users\kuba\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 124, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "c:\users\kuba\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 64, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    import _win32sysloader
ImportError: DLL load failed: Listed\xfd module not found.
```

The last row is translated, because it was in my language. (`ImportError: DLL load failed: Uveden\xfd modul nebyl nalezen.`, in Czech)

Does anybody know what do with this?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [`pyinstaller` manual](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/installation.html#installing-in-windows):

> For Windows, PyWin32 or the more recent pypiwin32, is a prerequisite.

Try installing one of those.